# Sort JSON or get JSON in original order

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json, sorting

Since it is not possible to get a JSON file with the original order, I'd like to sort it in JS again. The file looks like this:

```
{
    "index": 5,
    "timestamp": 1570438008,
    "data": {
        "12": [
            "Title 2",
            "Description 2"
        ],
        "10": [
            "Title 1",
            "Description 1"
        ]
    }
}
```

If I access this JSON file now from JS, I get another order than the original:

```
$.ajax({
    url: '../json/smiirl_data.json',
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(response) {
        console.log(response['data']);
    }
});
```

console.log from JS shows:

```
{
    "10": [
        "Title 1",
        "Description 1"
    ],
    "12": [
        "Title 2",
        "Description 2"
    ]
}
```

Is it possible to sort (title descending) it? I need the orignal order (12, 10).

Comment: Key order is not guaranteed. If you need them sorted, return an array of `[ id, data ]` pairs.

Comment: @Mr.Polywhirl in ES6 compliant environments it *is* but then you cannot have numeric keys in reverse order. In non-ES6 compliant environments, you just don't have a guarantee. So it's a lose-lose situation. As always, the suggestion is that if you want ordered objects, use an array.

Comment: @VLAZ Can you give me an example for my code?

Comment: @Anuga I've tried this but I couldn't get it work. Can you give me an example for my code :)?

Comment: The real question is why do you want the order of your data to be a certain way?

Comment: @LeeTaylor I create some html content from this JSON file and the content should be sorted in a specific order for this.

Comment: @c3560231 Do you want to maintain the original order or sort descending?

Comment: @SudhakarRS It doesn't matter. I sorted the JSON file with php before. So if it is possible to maintain the original, I would be happy.

Comment: @c3560231 'Object.entries(response.data).sort((a,b)=>{return b[0]-a[0]})' will sort

Answer (score 2):

at first you need to serialize object to array after that you use sort function to sort it.

```
var array = [],
    data = response['data'];

    for (var array in data ) {
         array.push([array, data[vehicle]]);
    }

     array.sort(function(a, b) {
        return b[1] - a[1];
     });
```

Answer (score 0):

Because objects are not always guaranteed to maintain its order, and JSON does not support the [Map](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) class which guarantees the order, you should use an array instead, where there are two elements: the key and the value.

For example:

```
"data": [
  [12, ["Title 2", "Description 2"],
  [10, ["Title 1", "Description 1"]
]
```

The you can access it like:

```js
for(let item of myJSON.data)
{
  console.log('Key:', item[0]);
  console.log('Value:', item[1]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To guarantee order, re-structure your data to be a 2-dimensional array.

You can create an index map, and lookup function to make the data easier to query.

```js
let data = {
  "index": 5,
  "timestamp": 1570438008,
  "data": [
    [ "12", [ "Title 2", "Description 2" ] ],
    [ "10", [ "Title 1", "Description 1" ] ]
  ]
}

let indexMap = indexLookupMap(data.data); // Build an index
console.log(lookupEntry(data.data, indexMap, '10')); // Find entry with id '10'

data.data.forEach(entry => {
  console.log(`key => ${entry[0]}, value => ${entry[1].join(', ')}`);
})

function lookupEntry(data, indexMap, id) {
  return data[indexMap[id]][1];
}

function indexLookupMap(data) {
  return data.reduce((dict, entry, idx) => Object.assign(dict, { [entry[0]]: idx }), {});
}
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { top: 0; max-height: 100% !important; }
```